# How can I pass a Chapel string to a C function that requires (non-const) char*?

Tags: chapel

Suppose I have a Chapel string

```
var s : string;
```

How would I send it to a function that expects a `char*`(since `c_string` assumes `const char *`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that does this

```
extern {
  #include <stdio.h>
  static void f(char* argument) {
    printf("%s\n", argument);
  }
}

var s: string = "hello";
f(s.c_str():c_void_ptr:c_ptr(c_char));
```

Note the cast to c_void_ptr which is necessary before Chapel 1.19.

Comment: Thanks for the quick PR: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/pull/12048